# spark worker is not failure resilience

Tags: apache-spark

I am going to check failure resiliency in spark.
There is some solutions to tolerate faults in executor, driver and master. for executor, worker restarts it. for driver we can use supervisor mode. for master we can use standby master.

But if a worker process downs, who must restart it? it seems that like other master-worker systems, master must do that, but not!

as we can see in http://techblog.netflix.com/2015/03/can-spark-streaming-survive-chaos-monkey.html, it is said that "**The Worker process gets automatically relaunched**", but in my system if a worker process dies, it will never restart.

what is the solution to restart workers?